# Splitting a String and Reading Every Part

Tags: c++

I'm trying to complete a program that reads from a file and calculates the GPA. Basically there are 16 sets of data with 3 types in every set - name, grades, and extra points. 
**Example text:**

Bugs Bunny
A B+ B A- B B C+ A B A-
100

The problem I am getting is at the middle part of the string, when taking in the grades. I am trying to read the entire line of grades, then read each grade itself, like "A" then "B+". Basically read "A", the value is 3, add it to an accumulator, then move to the next letter grade until the newline character is reached.

I thought of using .get but that's for taking in values. I don't really understand how to process the grades from the string. I know a loop is used, however.

```
    struct infoTaker
{
   string theirName;
   string theirGrade;
   double theirDonation;
   int totalValue;
};


int main( )
{
double donation;
char letter;
ifstream file;
string fullName, actualGrade, substring;
file.open("F://Yes/thing.txt");
for ( int i = 0; i < 16; i ++){
     getline( file, fullName ); // getting the names
     infoTaker person;
     person.theirName = fullName; 
     cout << person.theirName << endl; // end of names section

     getline(file, actualGrade); // gettting the entire line
     person.theirGrade = actualGrade;  // the string of grades  
        cout << letter << endl; // Don't know what to do here

     file >> donation;
     file.ignore( 3 , '\n');
     person.theirDonation = donation;

     cout << person.theirGrade << endl;
     cout << person.theirDonation << endl;
     double convertDoodahs = person.theirDonation / 2.0;
     }  
}
```

Comment: You want all grades in different strings? Or some integer values denoting grades.

Comment: I am finding the value of each grade in the string, then adding them to an accumulator and printing out the total

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it by adding the contents you read in a file, or you can also just read that certain line of grades. Im guessing this will be more useful because you can then later retrieve the name and other info.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main(){

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string temp;
    std::string grades;

    std::ifstream input("test.txt");

    //add them to vector, and access them later
    while(getline(input, temp)) vec.push_back(temp);

    //read the grades and seperate them 
    std::stringstream ss(vec[1]);
    while(ss >> grades){
        std::cout << grades << "\n";
    }
}
```

sample txt file

```
Bugs Bunny
A B C D+
100
```

output

```
A
B
C
D+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int convert(char a,char b='\0')
{
    int result = 0;
    if(b == '\0')
    {
        switch(a)
        {
        case 'A':
            result = 9;
            break;

        case 'B':
            result = 9;
            break;

        case 'C':
            result = 9;
            break;
        }
    }else
    {
        switch(a)
        {
        case 'A':
            if(b=='+')
            result = 10;
            else
            {
                result = 8;
            }
            break;

        case 'B':
            if(b=='+')
            result = 10;
            else
            {
                result = 8;
            }
            break;

        case 'C':
            if(b=='+')
            result = 10;
            else
            {
                result = 8;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int getSum(string g)
{
    int ans = 0;
    int l = g.length();
    for(int i=0;i<l;)
    {
        char a = g[i++],b='\0';
        if(g[i]=='+'||g[i]=='-')
        {
            b = g[i++];
        }
        ans+=convert(a,b);
        i++;
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    string g = "A B+ B A- B B C+ A B A-";
    int sum = getSum(g);
}
```

try this...